# How to add JS to the search form?

Tags: 8

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {

     $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mylibrary';

  }

}
```

Doing a `dpm($form)` on the search form, I see it has the my attached library, so what gives?

---

**Solution:**

The above code works fine, turns out it was my js code, I had copied over from another js file and it had an if statement that somehow I missed (it was 4 am). Credit @[Alexei Rayu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207176/how-to-add-js-to-the-search-form/207177?noredirect=1#comment-252436)

Comment: Did you check using a different theme to see if you have a form alter at that level removing extra JS?  Also did you do the basic cache rebuild (seems likely you did but always worth double checking)?

Comment: I think the "solution" part of this question should be move to an additional answer (though the same info is also already include in your comment below the accepted answer,, so maybe its just redundant?)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens yes, it would be redundant, I just added to the Q to not confuse future readers.

Comment: Indeed ... like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 8, you first need to define assets in a library in your theme or module: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

and then you can attach that library to your form like this:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mylibrary';
```

Comment: thx, but I've a .libraries.yml already. As mentioned in my Q, when I go to `node/1/edit` it works, ugh, I guess shouldn't have named it js on my example, my bad.

Comment: The form has a different id on the search page. Check out if you need to adjust form identification.

Comment: but I didn't specify an id, which means, it should apply to all forms, right?

Comment: True. Can you check if you see JS errors in the browser console? If none, then you can also do ctrl+U and check if the JS file is actually loaded on that page.

Comment: turning off js aggregation and ctrl+U I see it gets loaded. The mystery grows...no console errors either...

Comment: are you using 'drush cr' ?: )

Comment: `drush cr` `drupal cr` same result : (

Comment: So the file DOES get loaded. Then, the problem is in the JS code. Should you add your JS code to the ticket?

Comment: turns out it was my js code, I had copied over from another js file and it had an if statement that somehow I missed. Thx for your help!