# How do I add a JavaScript file to a form?

Tags: 8, forms, javascript

I'm trying to add a JavaScript file to a form that I have in a modal.  Although I followed the information found [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme), [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2575207), and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207176/how-to-add-js-to-the-search-form), the file doesn't appear in the Network tab of the inspector and nothing is logged to the browser console when the modal is launched.

The form modal is triggered in
themes/custom/my_theme/templates/controllers/my-controller-theme.html.twig.

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/help/{{ var1 }}/{{ var2 }}/add">Click here to add</a>
```

The library is defined in my custom theme in themes/custom/my_theme/my_theme.libraries.yml.

```
my_modals:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/my_modals.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

The JavaScript file is themes/custom/my_theme/js/my_modals.js.

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.my_modals = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            console.log('test');
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

The form itself is defined in my custom profile in
profiles/my_profile/src/Form/MyModalAddForm.php.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // ...
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_theme/my_modals';
}
```

Comment: what are you returning in buildForm ? how is your routing setup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being related to namespaces.  My profile and theme had the same name so Drupal didn't know where to load the JS from.

Answer (score 0):

There is no use to attach libraries to a form that is displayed in a modal window because the window has no place for assets (JS and CSS files). Instead I would suggest using [hook_page_attachements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.2.x) or attaching the library to page element that is responsible for triggering that modal window.